# Is this use of the verb 'tell' correct?

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

Is this use of the verb 'tell' correct?

Suppose we have this situation. Mary tells Jack to wait at home until she comes back.
Can I  say this?

> Jack waited at home **as told**.

I'm also in doubt whether I should add 'to' after 'told'.

> Jack waited at home **as told to**.

Comment: We can say _as instructed_, but _as told_ on its own doesn't seem right to me, probably because _to tell_ can have various meanings. It would be better to say _as he had been told to do_ or _as Mary had told him_.

Comment: I think _...as he'd been told to_ is also colloquial, though perhaps informal. An angry parent says, _"Do as you're told!"_ but _"...as told"_ is more commonly used of stories: "Here's the story as told by an eye-witness."

Comment: If you are going to use "told" (see Kate's comment) then it would probably be best to say Jack waited at home **as he was told to do**. That is unambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of handling things like this is to write them out as fully as possible, with no implied words, such as:

> Jack waited at home, just as he had been told to do.

This is grammatically correct, and it is how one might formally write the sentence.

But for informal writing, or when speaking, many of those words can be dropped without changing the meaning:

- Jack waited at home, *just* as he had been told to do.
- Jack waited at home, as he had been told to *do*.
- Jack waited at home, as he had been told *to*.
- Jack waited at home, as *he had been* told.
- Jack waited at home, as told.

These all convey the same meaning, without any ambiguity or awkwardness.

Other variations are possible, and it could even be rearranged:

- As he had just been told to do, Jack waited at home.
- …
- As told, Jack waited at home.

(Notice that the placement of "just" changes the meaning slightly.)

---

A subtler point, which won't be noticed by learners (or even many native speakers), is that the various forms *do* actually have slightly different meanings, at least in terms of what is implicitly stressed.
This might be used in more poetical forms of writing, where every word is important.

Consider list from the bottom up, with the italicised expressions being added.
Each expression emphasizes a new aspect:

- "he had been" reminds the reader that this happened recently, as opposed to a standing rule that has been in effect for a long time.
- "to" makes it more obvious that the "waited" is important, as opposed to the "at home".
- "do" stresses that this is something he must actively do, perhaps requiring attention and some effort.
- "just" implies that he waited in exactly the manner he had been told.
  (Or it means very recently if placed as "just been told".)